# Why while loop differently work in java and c

Tags: java, c

I have the question always in mind, c and java both have different output when I am trying to do following

**In C:**

```
int i=5;

while(i--)
{
   printf(i);
}
```

> output: 54321

**and in java**

```
int i=5;

while(i--)       // Compilation error 
{
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Why ? Compilation error occured in while condition

Comment: Because the language designers said so.

Comment: There are multiple issues with both the codes. Consider yourself *unlucky* because `printf(i);` worked. It should've been `printf("%d\n", i);`

Comment: Also, don't compare two languages. They are two different stuff, having their own similarities and differences.

Comment: Besides the gifen ansers, I would consider this as a bad programming style. It is not well readable. Be always explicit and write something like while (i-- > 0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java, there is a separation between the integral types (int, long, etc...) and the boolean type. Therefore an expression that returns an int cannot be used where a boolean is required.

Therefore the condition in Java must be :

```
while (i-- > 0)
```

In C, an int equal to 0 can be treated as false, which is why `while (i--)` is valid.

P.S. I'm assuming that the missing initialization of `i` in the Java code is a omission.

Comment: Sir, you may also wish to include that `null` is considered to be false in C, to make your answer more complete.

Comment: @DebosmitRay That's true, but not entirely related to the question, since the expression in the question is never null.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification, sir. :)

Comment: To be consistent with the C version, it should be `!= 0`.

Comment: @Andreas I don't remember how C treats negative values when used as booleans, but since the initial value in the code snippet is positive, `i-- > 0` is consistent with the C code.

Comment: @Eran As you already said yourself, `0` is `false`, every other `int` value is `true`. Quick search found [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions), though it's C++, but it says: *The value zero (for integral, floating-point, and unscoped enumeration) and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member values become `false`. All other values become `true`.*

Comment: @Eran, Sir here another question: